# Pimary keys in db

Tags: mysql

Thanks folks! This from an online Khan academy tutorial on sql:

1) How do I know that student_id in students_grades is related to id in student?
2) Why is there no value for primary key in students?

Thanks a lot.

```
CREATE TABLE students (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name TEXT,
    last_name TEXT,
    email TEXT,
    phone TEXT,
    birthdate TEXT);

INSERT INTO students (first_name, last_name, email, phone, birthdate)
    VALUES ("Peter", "Rabbit", "peter@rabbit.com", "555-6666", "2002-06-24");
INSERT INTO students (first_name, last_name, email, phone, birthdate)
    VALUES ("Alice", "Wonderland", "alice@wonderland.com", "555-4444", "2002-07-04");

CREATE TABLE student_grades (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
student_id INTEGER,
test TEXT,
grade INTEGER);

INSERT INTO student_grades (student_id, test, grade)
    VALUES (1, "Nutrition", 95);
INSERT INTO student_grades (student_id, test, grade)
    VALUES (2, "Nutrition", 92);
INSERT INTO student_grades (student_id, test, grade)
    VALUES (1, "Chemistry", 85);
INSERT INTO student_grades (student_id, test, grade)
    VALUES (2, "Chemistry", 95);
```

Comment: What have you tried, to solve this problem and read up about this topic, *before* posting on Stack Overflood?

Comment: Using `TEXT` for columns like this is massive overkill, nobody has a 65,535 character name. Use `VARCHAR(255)` as a default as it's reasonably long, yet doesn't leave things open for people to jam in absurd amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I know that student_id in students_grades is related to id in student?

It isn't, except by implication. The code fails to [create a relationship](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

> Why is there no value for primary key in students?

Neither set of INSERT statements specify a value for the primary key. They all let the database generate one automatically. This ensures there is no conflict.

Comment: This schema won't generate one automatically, there's no `AUTO_INCREMENT` set.